# Applying parallelization when updating dictionary values

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas, dictionary, parallel-processing

```
datasets = {}
datasets['df1'] = df1
datasets['df2'] = df2
datasets['df3'] = df3
datasets['df4'] = df4

def prepare_dataframe(dataframe):
    return dataframe.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower().str.replace('[^\w\s]', ''))

for key, value in datasets.items():
    datasets[key] = prepare_dataframe(value)
```

I need to prepare the data in some dataframes for further analysis. I would like to parallelize the for loop that updates the dictionary with a prepared dataframe. This code will eventually run on a machine with dozens of cores and thousands of dataframes. On my local machine I do not appear to be using more than a single core in the prepare_dataframe function.

I have looked at Numba and Joblib but I cannot find a way to work with dictionary values in either library.

Any insight would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `multiprocessing` library. You can read about its basics [here](https://pymotw.com/3/multiprocessing/basics.html).

Here is the code that does what you need:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def prepare_dataframe(dataframe):
    # do whatever you want here
    # changes made here are *not* global
    # return a modified version of what you want
    return dataframe

def worker(dict_item):
    key,value = dict_item
    return (key,prepare_dataframe(value))

def parallelize(data, func):
    data_list = list(data.items())
    pool = Pool()
    data = dict(pool.map(func, data_list))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return data

datasets = parallelize(datasets,worker)
```